# Unable to run unit tests in PHPStorm's IDE

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, composer-php, phpstorm

When I run `vendor/bin/phpunit` my tests all run successfully.  However, when I right click on a tests file and click "Run tests" I end up seeing:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -dxdebug.coverage_enable=1 /private/var/folders/bj/t2w187x158g7rgghctgknwb80000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php --coverage-clover /Users/bkuhl/Library/Caches/WebIde70/coverage/services$tests.coverage --no-configuration /Users/bkuhl/Projects/myproject/services/app/tests
Testing started at 3:09 PM ...

Fatal error: Class IDE_PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener::addRiskyTest) in /private/var/folders/bj/t2w187x158g7rgghctgknwb80000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php on line 504
PHP Fatal error:  Class IDE_PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener::addRiskyTest) in /private/var/folders/bj/t2w187x158g7rgghctgknwb80000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php on line 504
Call Stack:
    0.0008     340040   1. {main}() /private/var/folders/bj/t2w187x158g7rgghctgknwb80000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php:0

PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /private/var/folders/bj/t2w187x158g7rgghctgknwb80000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php:0

Process finished with exit code 255
```

I have PHPStorm configured to use `path/to/vendor/autoload.php`

[image]
I've temporarily changed the path of this directory for the purpose of this screenshot, but it is a perfectly valid path.

Has anyone run into issues using PHPStorm's ability to run your tests?

**composer.json:**

```
"require-dev": {
    "way/generators": "dev-master",
    "way/laravel-test-helpers": "dev-master",
    "mockery/mockery": "*",
    "codeception/aspect-mock": "*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.9.*@dev"
},
```

Comment: What phpstorm version do you run? And what is the phpunit version?

Comment: @zerkms - That would've been good information for me to include.... v7.1.1

Comment: ... and what about **PHPUnit version** ?? .. Or should I just guess that it is 3.8 ?

Comment: @LazyOne 3.9 - I updated the post to show my composer configuration

Answer (score 43, accepted):

PhpStorm uses wrapper/helper script when executing PHPUnit tests (for integration purposes: monitor execution progress, stack trace etc).

At the moment that helper script does not support PHPUnit 3.8 or 3.9 -- only 3.7 and below.

Corresponding ticket: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-21666 -- watch it (star/vote/comment) to get notified when it will be resolved.

**P.S.**
This issue is now fixed and fix will be available in next public EAP build (newer than current 134.1456).

Comment: Unfortunately it still affects IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.6. If only I could override how it generates the temporary file...

Comment: I just ran into this with PhpStorm 7.1.3.  PHPUnit is currently at 4.2.0!  Guess I'll have to downgrade.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution:
Set

```
"phpunit/phpunit": "3.7"
```

in **composer.json**

and run

```
composer update
```

Then the issue will be resolved.

this worked for me also...

[IntelliJ IDEA won't run PHPUnit 4.0 tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799619/intellij-idea-wont-run-phpunit-4-0-tests/22799620#22799620)

Comment: I got the same problem with jenkins.. Thank you !

Answer (score 6):

Some user named **andriy komm** added solution based on manual fixing of php plugin in IDE in ticket thread (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-21666):

> A workaround until it is fixed:
>
> 1. go to /plugins/php/lib
> 2. make a backup of php.jar
> 3. Use whatever tool you have to open the file, usually zip or other compress tools or under ubuntu the file roller.
> 4. Go to scripts/phpunit.php
> 5. Modify it, searching for the "IDE_PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener" class and adding there the following line:
>
> public function addRiskyTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, Exception
>   $e, $time) {}
>   6. save the file and update the php.jar
>
> Note 1:  depending on OS and tool you use, you might have to unpack
>   the .jar to modify and compress it back to jar again. Using file
>   roller on ubuntu I could skip this step, edit the file and update the
>   jar directly.
>
> Editing the /tmp/ide-phpunit.php DOES not help, because it get
>   overriden by the phpunit.php file, which I mentioned above.
>
> Note 2: Also depending on the version, you might find the php.jar
>   elsewhere:
>
> Either here: Go to your users home directory (windows/linux) and
>   search vor a hidden directory .Webide, while  is a number
>   depending on your phpstorm version (e. G. .Webide70)
>
> Or here: I think earlier versions were named like .IntelliJIdea
>   while  is a number depending on your phpstorm version.
>
> And there use the same path (/plugins/php/lib)

Worked for me (Windows 7, PHPStorm 7, #PS-133.982).