# IntelliJ IDEA won't run PHPUnit 4.0 tests

Tags: intellij-idea, phpunit

Sometimes IntelliJ IDEA has problems running, debugging, or showing code-coverage for PHPUnit tests. This can occur when the classes it generates are not compatible with the version of PHPUnit you have.

In my case, it's IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.6  versus PHPUnit 4.0.14, which always fails with this message:

```
/usr/bin/php /tmp/ide-phpunit.php --configuration /home/username/Documents/stuff/phpunit.xml.dist
Testing started at 5:32 PM ...
PHP Fatal error:  Class IDE_PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener::addRiskyTest) in /tmp/ide-phpunit.php on line 496
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /tmp/ide-phpunit.php:0

Process finished with exit code 255
```

The code it is generating in `/tmp/ide-phpunit.php` does not contain a new method required by PHPUnit 4.x.

Things which I've tried that **don't** work:

- Fixing the file manually and marking it read-only causes IntelliJ to stop and complain that it cannot replace the file.
- Setting up a "run-before" command to automatically patch the file is insufficient, because it doesn't seem to work for debugging nor code-coverage, only regular runs.

Comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-24198

Comment: @SamDark : There are several older tickets about it, I'm not going to hold my breath hoping that it'll get fixed in a timely manner.

Comment: Sure. I've just made sure Jetbrains are aware of the issue and it seems they were not.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The best solution I've found is to patch your IntelliJ installation with a manual fix. These instructions assume Linux paths, but the same basic process should be possible on Windows.

### Find the JAR

First, find the `php.jar` file in your IntelliJ installation. JAR files are a kind of ZIP file, you can open (and modify) both of them with the same tools. On my system, it was present at:

```
/home/username/.IntelliJIdea12/config/plugins/php/lib/php.jar
```

Make a backup of `php.jar`, since we're going to edit it.

### Extract the template

Using a popular ZIP-file tool (like 7-Zip) open `php.jar`, and find the compresesd file inside called:

```
scripts/phpunit.php
```

Extract this file to a temporary location where you can edit it.

### Add the method to the template

Inside the file, we need to find the class `IDE_PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener`, which in my case is around line `303`. On that class, we need to add a new method:

```
public function addRiskyTest(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, Exception $e, $time){}
```

Save the file when you are done.

### Update the JAR with the new template

Now overwrite `scripts/phpunit.php` inside the JAR with your new version. Depending on your ZIP tool, this might have been as easy as double-clicking the file to open it, saving your changes, and clicking a confirmation prompt, but it depends on what you're using.

### Restart IntelliJ

Now you should be done! Running, debugging, or generating code-coverage data with PHPUnit should be just a convenient click of a button.

Note that if you update your PHP plugin, it will probably overwrite the fix and you'll need to re-apply it again.

Comment: I prefer sticking to the LTS version of PhpUnit until JetBrains fixed this. As Andrey wrote in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531584/how-to-setup-phpunit-for-intellij-idea-13-1-on-ubuntu-13-10 they are working on it.

Comment: Remark: for PhpStorm on Windows, the ``php.jar`` is under ``{Program Files}\JetBrains\PhpStorm {version}\plugins\php\lib\php.jar``.

Comment: On OSX, use `unzip php.jar` to extract the jar (into the current directory, use a temp dir!) and `jar cf php.jar *` to re-pack the jar.