# Not able to run codecoverage with PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

I am trying to run unit test in PhpStorm with codecoverage.
It throws me a error msg saying interpreter is missing. How to install the interpreter!

Also how to configure in order to run my tests with code coverage.

[image: Edit Configuration]

Answer (score 1):

Steps to do:

### 1. Set interpreter and language level.

File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP

Select your PHP version. Then click button with `...` (three dotes), then add interpreter.

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/interpreters.html

### 2. Add PHPUnit to project.

File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHPUnit

**a) Load form include path**

To add this you must set where PHPUnit library is installed. Then add using `External Libraries` in `Project`.

[image: adding include paths]

To specify path use green `+` button.

**b) Use custom autoloader**

Use this option when you install PHPUnit via composer. In `Path to script` field specify autoload file.

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/phpunit.html

### 3. Configure tests

In the top right corner use `Select Run/Debug Configuration` menu

[image: run debug configration]

And click `Edit Configurations`. Select green `+` button to add PHPUnit.

[image: add phpunit]

Define name of the configuration and directory with tests. Additionally you can add some PHPUnit arguments in `Test Runner options` field.

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/run-debug-configuration-phpunit.html

### Annotation 1 - Configure bootstrap

Tests sometimes needs to use a bootstrap file which set environments, loads configs etc. To set this file go to:

File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHPUnit

and select the bootstrap file in `Default bootstrap file` field.

[image: bootstrap file]

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/phpunit.html - in `Bootstrap file` section.

### Annotation 2 - Run tests with code coverage

To run with coverage you must install Xdebug PHP extension. [You should read the Xdebug installation guide](http://xdebug.org/docs/install).

After this actions use a icon

[image: coverage]

to run with coverage.

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/code-coverage.html

Comment: I tried the steps and it says me error saying empty test suit.

Comment: Can you run test normally, without coverage?

Comment: Yes i have unit test in the directory specified in the configuration .

Comment: C:\xampp\php\php.exe -d-a=--interactive -d-c=-php-ini C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php --configuration C:\xampp\php\phpunit C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\xxxxxx\xxxx\cxxx\xxxx\tests\core\framework
Testing started at 7:22 PM ...

Process finished with exit code 255

Comment: Configuration must be in xml format, you pass --configuration C:\xampp\php\phpunit

Comment: The steps were very useful and i am able to run the unit tests now. one other issue encountered during run was fixed using the link . [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799619/intellij-idea-wont-run-phpunit-4-0-tests)

Comment: Can you use code coverage without unit test? I have a shell script that is not PHPUnit. I could of course convert the script into a PHPUnit test if need be.